# Splitting out rows with multiple values in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to split out few values from a database.

[image: Sample data]

There are two columns, Test and Test_Parameter. I want to extract those rows which have different "test_parameter" values for same "Test" value. For example, in my screenshot, I want "Grade:" to be selected as it has different values of Test_Parameter. I know it has a very simple solution but I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select test
from t
group by test
having min(test_parameter) <> max(test_parameter);
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks a lot for the reply! I was just wondering about the max and min function used by you. Can you please explain that to me?

Comment: Max and Min are table functions that can be referenced here in the Snowflake documentation: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/min.html

Comment: @AshishKumar . . . These are aggregation functions and a very basic part of SQL.

Comment: Yeah I have used them before, but in my case it was a string, so I was asking the context for which you have used.

Answer (score 0):

I might be confused by the ask, but wouldn't this work?

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE test <> test_parameter
```

Comment: Yeah I just tried this statement myself while I was posting this question over here. This is the simplest solution available I guess. But I was not sure about this as it is too simple.

Comment: Sometimes, it's just that easy.  :-) One thing to be careful about is the case-sensitivity.  If you want it to be case insensitive, then you should wrap an UPPER() or LOWER() around both test and test_parameter.

Comment: I think this answer may have understood the question differently while producing the same output. To test that, just add in another test with just one test_parameter such that test<>test_parameter, then run all the answers. The question is -Are you trying to output test where test value doesn't equal corresponding test_parameter value? --VS-- Are you trying to output tests whose test_parameters are not homogeneous? If former, go with this answer. If latter, go with Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of below to remove colon and compare :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT test FROM table1 WHERE test NOT LIKE test_parameter||'%'

    SELECT DISTINCT test FROM table1 WHERE SUBSTR(test,1,INSTR(test,':')-1) <> test_parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Gordon's answer better, but a maybe simple you understand albeit I suspect slower method would be:

```
SELECT test 
FROM (
    SELECT test,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(test_parameter) AS c
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY 1
)
WHERE c > 1
```

the above is if you really don't want the counts in the results, otherwise the `having` clause makes its simpler:

```
SELECT test,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(test_parameter) AS c
FROM table1
GROUP BY 1
HAVING c > 1
```